# Post Ubuntu Installation :

Tags: 14.04

Post Ubuntu Installation is it necessary to install the motherboard drivers . As I used to install after installing WINDOWS OS . Because after I installed the Ubntu 14.04 succesfully  I insterd my motherboard cd as usual I was giveing the archive error .plz reply

Comment: Post Installation of Ubuntu 14.04 , you do not have to install any other MotherBoard Drivers. It is like plug and play.                                                      You do not have to install any kind of Motherboard Drivers seperately post installation of  even the latest Windows OS's such as Windows 10 Home or Professional .  You get the best browser bydefault Mozilla Firefox, a video player to play movies

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need that and you probably have the majority, if not all, of the drivers that you want already installed and working.

Usually the only drivers that you need are the ones related to the GPU, if you go to

```
Software & Updates > Additional Drivers
```

it will tell you what you can download and install from there.

Comment: Post Installation of Ubuntu 14.04 , you do not have to install any other MotherBoard Drivers. It is like plug and play.

Answer (score 0):

When you did the installation, did you also connect the computer to the internet and allow updates to download?

If you did that and if the system did not detect any 'Additional Drivers' as someone has already answered, you should be good to go.

Only specialised devices or hardware need additional drivers to be installed after the standard installation.

If you are encountering some problems then if you explain the problem, someone here may be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

See, carry on sudo apt-get update && sudo apt update followed by sudo apt-get upgradae && sudo apt upgrade.

It duly completes the installation.

Ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto